# PHP jQuery script modification/correction

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have on page this table:

[image]

It's just result of query that returns records belonging to current user.
I added delete button.

I'm jquery&ajax **newbie** and i invented this task to myself.
I wanted to handle button using these technologies.
It should delete one row in table.

With my weak skills i could do this only in 1 way

```
    $user=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $con = db_connect();

    $result = $con->query("SELECT  `id_app`, `date_cr`,`id_user`
                            FROM `applications`
                            WHERE id_user = $user");
    if(($data = $result->num_rows)==0){
            echo '<p class="error">No data</p>';                
            exit;
    }
    else
    {           
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="./functions/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>';   

        echo '<br/><br/><table id="tab_history">
        <tr><td>Time when created</td><td></td></tr>';

        while(($data = $result->fetch_assoc())!==null)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$data['date_cr'].'</td><td>';
            echo '<button id="btnDel'.$data['id_app'].'" type="button">
            Delete</button></td></tr>';

            echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#btnDel'.$data['id_app'].'").click(function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();

                if (confirm(\'Are you sure?\')){
                    var id_app = '.$data['id_app'].';
                    var id_user = '.$data['id_user'].';

                    var info = \'id_app=\'+id_app+\'&id_user=\'+ id_user;

                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "./functions/del_app.php",
                       data: info,
                       success: function(){                             
                        location.reload();                          
                        }   
                    });                                         
                }                     
                });         
            </script>'; 
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
```

It's fine, it's deleting, so i don't attach function file.

But it's really stupid method:P. I'm adding script to each row. I have been thinking how to make it with one script but had no idea. Maybe button class?

I really would like to know how to get the same effect with one script leaving buttons.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

Change the button id to a class "btnDel" and add a new custom attribute:

```
echo '<button class="btnDel" data-app-id="'.$data['id_app'].'"  data-user-id="'.$data['id_user'].'" type="button">
            Delete</button></td></tr>';
```

Put only once the javascript and change the code to retrieve the data you put in the attributes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".btnDel").click(function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();

                if (confirm(\'Are you sure?\')){
                    var id_app = $(this).attr('data-app-id'); // retrieve the app id
                    var id_user = $(this).attr('data-user-id'); // retrieve the user id
                    var row = $(this).parent().parent(); // retrieve the parent row so we can remove it without reloading the whole page

                    var info = \'id_app=\'+id_app+\'&id_user=\'+ id_user;

                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "./functions/del_app.php",
                       data: info,
                       success: function(){                             
                        $(row).remove(); // remove the row                          
                        }   
                    });                                         
                }                     
                });         
            </script>
```

After the delete is completed, notice that instead of reloading the whole page you could remove the row.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery then you should properly harness the powers of AJAX and working with php and javascript together. Not only will this offer a slick UX, but it's flexible and easy. I believe this tutorial will best suit your needs:

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/01/delete-record-using-ajax-get-method-and.html

Also, instead of echo'ing out all of your JavaScript, if you need to pass a variable in from php do it like so:

```
var myJavaScriptVariable = <?=myPHPvariable?>; //if its a number
var myJavaScriptVariable = '<?=myPHPvariable?>'; //if its a string
```

You could also initiate an AJAX request on page load to a php script then receive variables in that form

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific need of html tables ? If not, You can use jqgrid with checkbox available to each row. On selection of checkbox or a separate single delete button at the bottom of the page you can fire the delete operation on selecting a checkbox.

You can refer to demos available at http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html.

Answer (score 1):

According to my own experience, I would do the following :

```
<?php
$user=$_SESSION['userid'];
$con = db_connect();

$result = $con->query("SELECT  `id_app`, `date_cr`,`id_user`
                        FROM `applications`
                        WHERE id_user = $user");
?>

<?php if(($data = $result->num_rows)==0){ ?>

    <p class="error">No data</p>                

<?php } else { ?>           
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./functions/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>';   
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table id="tab_history">
        <tr>
            <td>Time when created
            <td>
        </tr>

    <?php while(($data = $result->fetch_assoc())!==null) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$data['date_cr'] ?>
            <td><button class="btnDel" data-id-app="<?=$data['id_app'] ?>" data-id-user="<?=$data['id_user'] ?>" type="button">
        Delete</button>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
<script>
$(".btnDel").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();

            if (confirm(\'Are you sure?\')){
                var id_app = $(this).attr('data-id-app');
                var id_user = $(this).attr('data-id-user');

                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "./functions/del_app.php",
                   data: {
                            id_app: id_app,
                            id_user: id_user
                         },
                   success: function(){                             
                    location.reload();                          
                   }   
                });                                         
            }                     
});         
</script>
```

Much more clearer, for me at least...